# UTM solution for Dynamic Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, parameters, dynamic-content, web-analytics-connector

We have a dynamic email template where we populate content via AMPscript from a Data Extension for different locales. I'd like to enable Web Analytics Connector for our account however I'm not quite sure how can we track different locales for dynamic emails since there will be only one email and our current UTM string is like following `utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%`. Is there any similar use cases?

Comment: Hi DBK. Please remember to [mark my answer as accepted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if it has been helpful. This will allow other users of SFSE to easily identify questions with valuable answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have an attribute in your sendable data extensions, which defines the locale/language preference of the recipient. Let's assume it is called "locale", what you could do is concatenate it to the WAC string, in case it exists and is not empty. So instead of:

```
utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%
```

You would do:

```
utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%%=CONCAT(emailname_,IIF(EMPTY(AttributeValue("locale")),'',CONCAT("_",AttributeValue("locale"))))=%%
```

Here you will append the value of your *locale* field, meaning a send of email named Campaign_2023 to a data extension without a *locale* field or with an empty locale value, the utm_campaign will be: Campaign_2023, while sending to a recipient with ES as locale value, you will get Campaign_2023_ES as utm_campaign.